# Coq compiler error: Impossible to unify "4" with "8". with VST make

Tags: verifiable-c

I have two questions:

First, if I write a C program with inline assembly, can I then verify the whole C program in VST? Or is it only pure C programs that can be verified?

Second, I tried to install the latest VST and Compcert as stated on http://vst.cs.princeton.edu/ on Ubuntu 12.04 but during some point an error occured during transformation of .v files to .vo files with a message of the form: 'Impossible to unify "2" with "8"'. I think this error occured during the make of compcert, but I'm not certain.

Then I tried to install VST on Ubuntu 14.04 using this guide: 'http://ninj4.net/2014/05/16/hello-vst-hello-verifiable-c.html'. I installed the same versions of Coq, OCaml and Menhir as the in the guide. Later when I ran make in the vst directory I got a similar problem as above. The following is what I got as output:

```
Makefile:289: .depend: No such file or directory  
coqdep -slash  -I msl -as msl  -I sepcomp -as sepcomp'...  
...  
...  
'COQC floyd/forward_lemmas.v  
COQC floyd/array_lemmas.v  
COQC floyd/data_at_lemmas.v  
COQC floyd/globals_lemmas.v  
File "/home/jhagl/verifiable-c/vst/floyd/data_at_lemmas.v", line 429, characters 49-60:  
Error: Impossible to unify "4" with "8".  
make: ** * [floyd/data_at_lemmas.vo] Error 1  
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

The following is a snippet from data_at_lemmas.v of the lemma that fails (I have marked line 429):

```
Lemma align_chunk_alignof: forall t ch, access_mode t = By_value ch -> legal_alignas_type t = true -> alignof t = Memdata.align_chunk ch.  
Proof.  
Transparent alignof.  
  intros.  
  destruct t; inversion H.  
  - unfold legal_alignas_type in H0.  
    simpl in H0.  
    destruct i, s; inversion H2; simpl;  
    destruct (attr_alignas a); try inversion H0; reflexivity.  
  - unfold legal_alignas_type in H0.  
    simpl in H0.  
    destruct s; inversion H2; simpl;  
    destruct (attr_alignas a); try inversion H0; admit. (* Tlong uncompatible problem *)  
  - unfold legal_alignas_type in H0.  
    simpl in H0.  
    destruct f; inversion H2; simpl;  
(\* Line 429 *)    destruct (attr_alignas a); try inversion H0; reflexivity.  
  - unfold legal_alignas_type in H0.  
simpl in H0.  
    inversion H2; simpl;
destruct (attr_alignas a); try inversion H0; reflexivity.  
Opaque alignof.  
Qed.
```

As an aside, i tried to run the following command in bash:
`./configure -toolprefix arm-none-eabi- arm-eabi -no-runtime-lib`
and got this error message:
`./configure: 65: shift: can't shift that many`
But `./configure -toolprefix arm-none-eabi- arm-eabi` worked. This was not a problem since I changed Makefile.config.

Any suggestions for how to fix this? I don't know Coq yet (I have just read a guide "Coq in a Hurry", and have used HOL though). I have other fresh systems on which I can try to install VST on (if that is necessary), even though I have tried twice already.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First:  inline assembly.  The recommended way to do inline assembly is to model it as a CompCert "inlineable external function call"; then you give a Verifiable C function specification for the function.  CompCert will generate inline assembly, not a real function call.  This is an advanced technique, I wouldn't suggest starting with it.

Second: build error.  Was it VST 1.5 from the vst.cs.princeton.edu website?  Was it an "internal compcert" (cd compcert; ./make), or an "external compcert"?  If external, 
do you have the right version of CompCert (2.1)?

Third, regarding "I don't know Coq yet."  Verifiable C will be hard to use if you
have no Coq experience.  I recommend Pierce et al's [Software Foundations](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf) to learn Coq.

Comment: It was VST 1.4 from vst.cs.princeton.edu and CompCert 2.3pl2 from http://compcert.inria.fr/release/compcert-2.3pl2.tgz. It was an "internal compcert" (which worked), but the make error occurred in vst (cd vst; ./make -j 2 all)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when installing VST 1.5 with CompCert 2.4. As a workaround I placed `admit` tactics at the problematic places. E. g. your lemma now looks like (pay attantion to the comment `(*!!! ... *)`):

```
Lemma align_chunk_alignof: forall t ch, access_mode t = By_value ch -> legal_alignas_type t = true -> alignof t = Memdata.align_chunk ch.
Proof.
Transparent alignof.
  intros.
  destruct t; inversion H.
  - unfold legal_alignas_type in H0.
    simpl in H0.
    destruct i, s; inversion H2; simpl;
    destruct (attr_alignas a); try inversion H0; reflexivity.
  - unfold legal_alignas_type in H0.
    simpl in H0.
    destruct s; inversion H2; simpl;
    destruct (attr_alignas a); try inversion H0; admit. (* Tlong uncompatible problem *)
  - unfold legal_alignas_type in H0.
    simpl in H0.
    destruct f; inversion H2; simpl.
    destruct (attr_alignas a). try inversion H0; reflexivity.
    reflexivity.
    destruct (attr_alignas a).  (* try inversion H0. *)
    inversion H0.
    admit. (* !!! that didn't work out. I can't proove 4=8 *)
  - unfold legal_alignas_type in H0.
    simpl in H0.
    inversion H2; simpl;
    destruct (attr_alignas a); try inversion H0; reflexivity.
Opaque alignof.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment (that it was VST 1.4), one possibility is that you have an incompatible (too new) version of Coq.  I suggest you might try VST 1.5, for two reasons:

1. VST 1.5 is compatible with more recent versions of Coq
    (and with CompCert 2.4, by the way)
2. New in VST 1.5, the Makefile checks explicitly which version of Coq you have,
   and gives a clear error message if you have an incompatible version.

So, there's no guarantee that this will solve the problem, but it might be a good start.